# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /www/app/loader.php on line 139

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /www/app/loader.php on
>   line 139

Строка 139

```
if(Login::getUser()['timezone'] !== Settings::get('default_timezone')
    and G\is_valid_timezone(Login::getUser()['timezone'])) {
```

Помогите исправить php 5.3

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Разыменование массивов, которые возвращают функции, [появилось](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration54.new-features.php) только в PHP 5.4. Для версий старше нужно сохранить результат вызова функции в промежуточную переменную. Потом адресовать нужный элемент массива.

```
$user = Login::getUser();
if ($user['timezone'] !== Settings::get('default_timezone')
    && G\is_valid_timezone($user['timezone'])) {
```